# What is the asymptotics of the Fourier transform of $\exp(-x^4)$ for large wave numbers?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-transform, hypergeometric-functions

The Fourier transform of $\exp(-x^4)$ has an analytical expression, it's the difference of two generalized hypergeometric functions:

$\int d x \ e^{-x^4} e^{ikx} = 2 \ \Gamma(\frac{5}{4}) \ _0F_2(;\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{k^4}{256}) - \frac{k^2}{4} \Gamma(\frac{3}{4}) _0F_2(;\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};\frac{k^4}{256})$

The asymptotics of the 0F2 is known, but the two series for large k just cancel, so how can one get the asymptotics of the Fourier transform of $\exp(-x^4)$ as  $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: You can find relevant expressions  here https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.4796.pdf

Comment: Thank you. However the expressions in the paper you linked considers the Fourier transform of $exp(-x^{\beta})$ where $\beta < 2$, they seem not to apply to $\beta = 4$.

Comment: What do you mean that the "two series for large k just cancel"? Are you saying that they have the same asymptotic expansion about $\infty$, or just the same leading term?

Comment: This https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0096300314006572 is behind a paywall. However the abstract is accessible and gives the asymptotic result.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: For completeness of MathOverflow, the Fourier transform $\Phi$ in question, according to the paper cited by Johannes Trost, satisfies $\Phi(k) \sim 2^{7/6} \, \sqrt{\pi/3}\, k^{-1/3} \exp(-(2^{1/3}\,3/16)\,k^{4/3}) \, \cos((3^{3/2}\,2^{1/3}/16)\,k^{4/3}-\pi/6)$.